# Help me prove this theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Seeing a magazine for Mathematical noticed that the following theorem was proven. It seemed interesting, but perhaps it is also very simple, so I thought to post it, thinking that would help me

Theorem: For any operator $A$, $\text {Lat } A^*=\left\{\mathcal{M}: \mathcal{M^{\bot}}\in\text {Lat } A\right\}$.

Note that:

$a)$ $\mathcal{M}$ is a subspace;

$b)$ The orthogonal complement of the subspace $\mathcal{M}$ is $\mathcal{M^{\bot}}=\left\{x\in\mathcal{H}:(x,y)=0, \forall y\in\mathcal{M}\right\}$

$c)$ $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space

$d)$ the ajdoint of $A$ is danoted by $A^*$

Please help me proving. Previously, thank you for your help

Comment: What is Lat $A$?

Comment: The collection of all subspaces of $H$ invariant under $A$ danoted $LatA$

Comment: Are you considering only continuous $A$, or more general?

Comment: I think it is about general operator without giving any specific concrete to

Comment: For linear operators in finite dimensional inner product space, I know you can prove $W$ is $A$ invariant if and only if $W^\perp$ is $A^\star$ invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Suppose we denote by $\,\langle\,,\,\rangle\,$  the inner product in our Hilbert space

$$U\in\text{Lat}\,A^*\implies A^*U\subset U\implies \forall\,u\in U\;,\;A^*u=u'\in U\;$$

Take now any $\,v\in U^\perp\;$ , so **for any** $\,u\in U\,$ we get :

$$\langle Av,u\rangle=\langle v,A^*u\rangle=\langle v,u'\rangle=0\implies Av\in U^\perp$$

and from here we get that $\;AU^\perp\subset U^\perp\implies U^\perp\in\text{Lat}\,A\;$

Now you try the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

For a closed subspace $L$ of a Hilbert space $H$, let $P_L$ denote the orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $L$.  Now observe the following:

1) For a bounded operator $A$ on $H$, a subspace $L$ is invariant for $A$ if and only if $P_L A P_L = AP_L$.

2) The orthogonal projection of $H$ onto $L^\perp$ is $I - P_L$ where $I$ denotes the identity operator.

Using these facts, you may now wish to compute: $(I-P_L)A^* (I-P_L)$.